# [X86][lvm] lld + fsplit-stack+ -fpatchable-function-entry error

Tags: lld

I'm getting an error with a lld link, ld is ok.

```
clang -fuse-ld=lld  -fsplit-stack -fpatchable-function-entry=1 t.c
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a;
  scanf("%d", &a);
  printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/

Is -fsplit-stack and -fpatchable-function-entry=1 incompatibility?

ld is ok, Is -fsplit-stack and -fpatchable-function-entry and lld incompatibility?

Comment: gotbolt:  https://godbolt.org/z/WP31Eofcc